Do I need transit visa at Bangkok while travelling from Japan to Kolkata? I have two different airlines
I am an Indian passport holder. Currently due to research work (work visa for one year) purpose I live in Japan. I am planning to travel to Kolkata and I have two PNR for two different flights transiting via Bangkok. So my query is: do I need any visa or transit visa for this during transiting via Bangkok?

No, you will not need any visa to complete this trip. Indian passport holders are visa exempt in Thailand. Should you need to check in for your connection or recheck bags, you can enter Thailand do so without a visa. See Visa Exemption and Visa on Arrival to Thailand.

I have to collect my luggage at the Thailand airport and then go for my next flight. There is total 7 hr layover on Bangkok between my arrival and departure of next flight. So do I need transit visa or any other documents?

You won’t need a visa. You should probably have a printed copy of your itinerary demonstrating your imminent departure from Thailand.
